# Adding a border to an SVG image element with SVG filters

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm looking for a way to add a border to an SVG image element using **SVG filters not CSS**, but I can't figure out how.

[image]

The file should be **stand-alone**, i.e. it is **not meant for a webpage**.  I'm working in Notepad++ intending to develop a script for batch processing were images may be of different sizes, and have different aspect ratios.

Although I could read the image dimension and position a rectangle on top, I was thinking that it may be possible to use SVG filters, as discussed [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Filter_effects).

Below is a MWE.

```
<svg
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">


  <defs>
    <filter id="image">
      <feImage xlink:href="abstract.jpg"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>


<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="DodgerBlue" />

  <rect x="10mm" y="10mm" width="20mm" height="30mm"
      style="filter:url(#image);"/>

</svg>
```

The example image in the MWE,

[image: Abstract pattern]

Image by [Pexels](https://pixabay.com/users/pexels-2286921/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1867395) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=1867395)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the image in an `<image>` tag and apply the filter to that. In this example I put `x="1"` and `y="1"` to distance the image from the edges since it can cut off the filter effect where the image is flush with the edge of the SVG.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 210 297" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <filter id="outline">
    <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded" operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="black"/>
    <feComposite in2="expanded" operator="in"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  <image filter="url(#outline)" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJwpE.jpg" height="200" width="200" x="1" y="1"/>
</svg>
```

Technique for adding border taken from [this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-add-a-double-border-to-svg-shapes/) article by CSS Tricks.